# Minor bug in furigana engine

Tags: bug, furigana

I just noticed a (very minor) bug in the furigana engine. If the post summary contains two URLs, like http://abc.de/ and http://klm.no/, the summary stops the hyperlink and the furigana engine interprets the `// .. //` markup, typesetting it in the system's IPA font:

> [image]

This just came up again.

> [image]

I guess this can be fixed by disabling the `//...//` markup for text of the form `//...https://` or `//...http://`.